# Bootstrap list items with multiple columns. Weird behaviour (includes JSBIN)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm try to list some items in multiple columns. Bootstrap keeps making weird formatting.

Here's the JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/huzurejunu/1/edit?html,css,output

[image]

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
      <strong>Checkbox list:</strong>
      <div class="row checklist">
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        more checkboxes....
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add css to override bootstrap and other css
add this css

```
.checklist .checkbox {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.checklist .checkbox+.checkbox {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```css
.checkbox {
  color: red;
}

.well {
    min-width: 250px;
}
.checklist .checkbox {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.checklist .checkbox+.checkbox {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="well">
      <strong>Checkbox list:</strong>
      <div class="row checklist">
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
          <label style="white-space: nowrap;"><input type="checkbox">Check box 1</label>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Interesting. I don't understand why it's just the margin that affects the first checkbox only.

Comment: Because there is another checkbox have different margin apply using .checkbox+.checkbox class

Comment: First checkbox apply margin different because making space between label and first checkbox but here we are using two checkbox in row so we have to change css